# Lua: setfenv() vs. _ENV

Tags: lua

What is the big deal with Lua switching from `setfenv()` to `_ENV`?

In various "What's New" sources, this move is mentioned as one of the most important changes between Lua versions 5.1 and 5.2.

However, the examples given in PIL and elsewhere can be trimmed to the following:

```
-- Lua 5.1                   -- Lua 5.2
function myfunc()            function myfunc()
    setfenv(1, {})               _ENV = {}
end                          end
```

So far, what we gained here is we have saved five key strokes. (I believe the situation is not much different from the C side.) Moreover, if I got it right, `setfenv()` can be used both from the outside and from the inside of a function, whereas `_ENV` can be accessed only from the inside of a function. (Of course, when using the C API, one can access the upvalues directly.) From what I wrote, the 5.2 approach seems much less flexible.

In his [The Novelties of Lua 5.2](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/talks/novelties-5.2.pdf), Roberto writes:

*"Being a syntactic sugar, it is much simpler than the old environments"*

Where's the simplicity? What have I overlooked?

I believe this topic is worth better treatment that it is given in the 5.2 User Manual.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Where's the simplicity?

It depends on how you define "simplicity".

In Lua 5.1, the environment was a magical, mystical setting that was unlike any other setting in the system. It didn't have an explicit place and it could only be set by using standard library features.

In Lua 5.2, the environment is a *variable*, just like any other. It has a name which you can use. So it's simpler in that it's more obvious what's going on.

Furthermore, in Lua 5.1, the environment of a function can be changed dynamically.

In Lua 5.2, outside of direct upvalue manipulation, once a function has an environment, that is the environment it will have in perpetuity. The environment for a function is inherited, being lexically scoped like a regular `local` variable. So if you look at your code, you can easily see what environment a function is in. If there is no `local _ENV` in the scope of that function's creation, then the environment shall be the environment of the chunk (which is defined by the `load` call).

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, the primary flaw of Lua 5.2's environments is that they cannot be set externally- i.e., you can't say `setfenv(func, {})`. This is, in my opinion, a huge failing. It is indeed simpler than Lua 5.1's environments, but not in a good way.

Comment: The reason for that is that environments are only a function of *Lua* code anymore; C functions exposed to Lua do not have environments. And thus, light C-functions are possible.

Comment: Indeed. However, being able to set the environment externally for Lua functions is really quite important.

Comment: You can set it externally, using debug.setupvalue. If a function accesses its environment, it inherits the _ENV of its parent as an upvalue. Here's a replacement of setfenv & getfenv: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-06/msg00313.html .

Comment: You shouldn't use the debug functions for regular functionality.

Comment: Changing the environment of a function after it has been loaded is not "regular functionality"; it breaks the concept of function encapsulation. All the situations where setting _ENV is OK do not require the debug library.

Comment: I found it a most useful thing to have, and in Lua 5.1, it was regular functionality. Not *every* function should be encapsulated.